# Azure CDN returns 403 forbidden

Tags: azure, cdn, http-status-code-403, ip-restrictions

The issue refers to the following scenario:

1. an Azure App Service
2. an Application Gateway with WAF v2. The backend pool contains the reference to the App Service.
3. a Microsoft Standard CDN
4. a Content Delivery Network WAF policy with associated the CDN endpoint

After creating on the App Service an IP restriction on the WAF public static IP, I get (403) Forbidden when I try to browse the CDN's public address. If I remove the restriction I can reach the CDN without any problem.

How can I maintain restrictions on the WAF IP and ensure that the CDN is reached?

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, we have changed in CDN's settings, the "Origin Hostname" and the "Origin hostname header" from "xxxxx.azurewebsites.net" to the custom domain's host name... and now it works!